# Top Author of the week

Tags: users, userpoints

How to get the Top Author of the week based on [user points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints)? I have tried http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_ranking but it has no such options. I am using drupal 7
I have [vote up/down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module and [user-points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module enabled and a [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to add user points for every vote automatically, based on that vote i want to have Top Author of the week.

Comment: Are we to assume that user points are assigned every time that a user posts a piece of content? Or every time a piece of content is viewed?  Could you expand on your use-case somewhat, otherwise this question is too ambiguous.

Comment: OK, you can assume that user points are assigned every time a user posts a piece of content... but any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I need this too.

Comment: No! but what i dead i have created a table and then i did put all the activities/points of a user id on that table and then i fetch the top author from that database table, that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

The Userpoints module has [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) integration to make this happen:

1. Create a new view using *Userpoints Transactions* as the base table.
2. Add a **Relationship**, *Userpoints Transactions: User*.
3. Select your **fields**: *User: uid* & *Userpoints Transactions: Points*.
4. **Filter** on *Userpoints Transactions: Timestamp* with the **Value Type** set to *An offset from the current time...* so you can input your [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) offset (e.g. by rolling week, "-7 day").
5. Enable the **Use aggregation** option.
6. Lastly, for the **Aggregation Settings** on *Userpoints Transactions: Points*, set the **Aggregation Type** to *Sum*.